# How to enable (or view) SQL log in Directus?

Tags: directus

How can I get the initial SQL error which caused this exception in Directus?

```
api[_].ERROR: Directus\Database\Exception\InvalidQueryException: Failed generating the SQL query.
in /var/www/directus/src/core/Directus/Database/TableGateway/BaseTableGateway.php:812
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a log within Directus, but you should be able to access this through your server logs.